# Recursively download site including files without extensions

Tags: linux, wget

I'm trying to download some files from an apache server with indexing turned on (so the pages are just hierarchical lists of links to files) however the files don't have extensions. I've tried wget with --accept=".*" but that doesn't work. It downloads the html ok.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I don't mind using a different tool.

Thanks 
Joe

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download the whole directory exploiting the recursive option. The following command should do:

```
wget -r http://your.remote.server/path/to/directory/
```

You can control the depth level of the recursion with the `-l` option.